# python try except format

Tags: python

```
try:
    num = int(input("Give me an integer between 1 and 100:"))
    while num > 100 or num < 1:
        print ("Sorry, that is not an integer between 1 and 100. Try again.")
        num = int(input("Give me an integer between 1 and 100:"))
except:
    print ("Sorry, that is not an integer between 1 and 100. Try again.")
else:
    print ("Thank you for your input")
```

How do I tell Python to also print "sorry try again" if they entered input such as "pear" or "sd23214"? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Why would you think it isn't doing that? 2. what have you tried? 3. Why do you have an "else" with no "if"?

Comment: Just put everything relevant in a `while` loop.

Comment: @Colleen, else can be used with `except` and `for` loops as well as `if`

Comment: @Colleen: `try: expr; except: doThisIfException; else: doThisifNoExceptionOccurred; finally: justDoThisRegardlessOfWhatHappened`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap it all in a `while` loop

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Give me an integer between 1 and 100:"))
        if num > 100 or num < 1:
            print ("Sorry, that is not an integer between 1 and 100. Try again.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print ("Sorry, that is not an integer between 1 and 100. Try again.")
    else:
        print ("Thank you for your input")
        break
```

Most people would probably not use the `else` clause here

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Give me an integer between 1 and 100:"))
        if num > 100 or num < 1:
            raise ValueError
        print ("Thank you for your input")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Sorry, that is not an integer between 1 and 100. Try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a better/easier way to do it (in my opinion):

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 100: "))
        if type(num) != int or num not in range(1, 101): #second argument is exclusive
            raise ValueError
        else:
            print("Thank you.")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be an integer within 1 and 100. Try again.")
```

Using a `range` is a nice way to do it rather than using `if num > 101 or num < 1`.

Comment: finding an element in a list (which is created by `range`) has an average time complexity of O(n), where `n = len(list)`, where as the other statement (`if num > 101 or num < 1`) has a complexity of O(1). So no, this is not a better solution.